# Database table columns names

Tags: sql, database, naming-conventions

I have noticed that some people in database columns instead of for example `id`, `user`, `address`are using something like `h_id`, `e_user`, `f_address` etc...

Is that some kind of security aspect? or maybe these are some shortcuts of words?

Comment: I can't see a relationship to security.  In the case of `user`, the goal might be avoiding a reserved word.  But really, you would need to look at the definitions of the columns or better yet ask the database deisgner what the intention is.

Answer (score 1):

Its because there might be many id fields like user_id,category_id,that's why they use so that code is understandable.

And talking about columns name like **f_address**, they are just shortcut for say **first address**. It doesn't have anything to do with security but to increase the query **readability** use proper name to fields so that people can understand just by seeing column name what data it saves.

If there are fields like category_id and sub_category_id , it is understandable from the field name, but if i denote it using c_id and s_id, its hard to depict.

Comment: Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved...In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not security related.

Some use it for readability or speed (you don't have to remember which table you gave a certain name->see following example) when writing queries.

i.e.

```
select a.name, b.name from table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id
```

Like this you have to remember that table1 is named a and table2 is named b etc.

But if you use tablename_field (which you can shorten by using only the first letter of the tablename). That way you never have duplicate fieldnames when creating join queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 'User' is a security object in SQL Server, so using that is kind of scary.  'ID' and 'address' are way too generic to provide any semantics when used as attribute names.

If a purpose of design is to be maintainable and readable, then there some words that simply don't work.